# json parsing in javascript for PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

in my phone gap, when the button is clicked it hits an api and in return i am getting a json array as response as follows

```
{"Status":[{ "Id": "46", "Username": "guru",image:"http://xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx//Tulips.jpg" }]}
```

i have stored this value in an var. Now i want to parse this response and i want to store the Id value and Username values and also the image in another var. How to do this

i tried by the following line

```
var data = JSON.parse(my_JSON_object);
        var  Username= data.Status.Itemlist[0].Username;
                    alert(UserName);
```

where in my_JSON_object i have stored the json array value.i got the username but the **image** is not displayed only the **url** gets displayed pls hlp me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is exactly the same as you have shown here:

```
var data = JSON.parse(my_JSON_object);

var id = data.Status[0].Id;
var name = data.Status[0].Username;
```

Comment: i tried your answer but i got an error in my logcat as follows  ERROR/Web Console(3230): TypeError: Result of expression 'my_JSON_object.Status' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:26

Comment: can u pls say how to display the images

Answer (score 0):

your missing the quotes on the "image" object part of your JSON.

your JSON:

```
    {"Status":[{ "Id": "46", "Username": "guru",image:"http://xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx//Tulips.jpg" }]}
```

Corrected JSON:

```
    {"Status":[{ "Id": "46", "Username": "guru","image":"http://xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx//Tulips.jpg" }]}
```